# Unsure of approach for Django custom user groups and permissions

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, usergroups

I am creating my first Django (ver 3.1) website which is simply a blog with a home page and store page. I want to create custom user groups that define specific roles (with unique permissions) for my blog.

These groups are:

- **Reader** - anonymous viewers and new accounts; has read permission for all content only
- **Author** - login required; has read and create permissions; edit and delete permissions for own content only
- **Moderator** - login required; has all CRUD permissions for all content
- **Admin** - login required, has all permissions (superuser)

All new users by default are in the **Reader** group. **Author** would either be assigned manually or eventually by an online form application to determine eligibility. **Moderator** and **Admin** would of course be manually assigned.

I am approaching this with possible future development, such as allowing user groups to be easily extended to other website pages. For example, a 5% discount for **Author** users applied to all store items, etc.

Which approach to creating user groups would be best for my situation? I have seen it done within the Django Admin Panel and by creating custom User Models via extending the AbstractBaseUser and UserBaseManager classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think extending the AbstractUser model is a good approach. How about something like this?

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    "Define the extra fields related to User here"""

    first_name = models.CharField(_('First Name of User'), blank=True, max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('Last Name of User'), blank=True, max_length=20)

    #  - - - Some more User fields according to your need s

    class Meta:
        permissions = (("can_read_content", "To provide read facility on all content"),
       #---------------------
                       )
```

Comment: In this approach, would I define CustomUser class for each user type, say class CustomUserReader? Or would I be instantiating this CustomUser class for each user type?